# convert list<int> to object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, object, highcharts

i am trying to create a chart in mvc with `highchart` so as you can see this is my chart:

```
  Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart1")
                      .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = "one"})
                      .SetYAxis(new YAxis { Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "تعداد مقالات" } })
                      .SetSeries(new Series { Data = new Data(new object[] {312}), Name = "محور های همایش" })
                      .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "" })
                      .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column });
```

The problem is here :

```
Data = new Data(new object[] {312})
```

Instead `312` i want to pass a `list<int>` that contains `312` as you can see here:

```
List<int> majorArticleCount=new List<int>();
Data = new Data(new object[] {majorArticleCount})
```

This list `majorArticleCount` contains `312` but i get this error :

```
 Parameter count mismatch.
```

How can i convert the list to object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what `Data` is but you might try something like this:

```
List<int> majorArticleCount = new List<int>();

majorArticleCount.Add(312);

Data = new Data(new object[] { majorArticleCount.ToArray()});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a list of int with 312 as the first(and only) item in it.

```
new List<int> {312};
```

So your code will be

```
Data = new Data(new object[] { new List<int> { 312 } })
```

Comment: As you can see  i want to convert my list<int> to object ,

Comment: See the updated answer. IT will add the list of int to an object array.